# Programmatically apply a CSS transition for a fixed duration

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-shapes

I have a little bookmark ribbon icon that I'm using in a WebView in an Android app. The ribbon is created entirely by using CSS and in it's default state, it's gray in color.

There are some instances where I want the bookmark to flash red and then slowly fade back to it's natural gray color. The behavior here will be very much akin to when you click a link to an SO answer -- when you get to the page with the answer that you clicked on, the answer background flashes orange and then slowly fades back to the default white. That's basically what I want to do with my ribbon color.

So, what's the best way to do this? (No JQuery, please -- I'd prefer straight javascript.) Here is my ribbon CSS:

```
div.ribbonDisplay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #c7c7c7;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    height: 6px;
    top: 8px;
    left: 7px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-bottom-width: 4px;
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, Harry. That's basically what I'm looking for. If you want to add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Already added mate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved with the below changes to the code.

1. Add an `id` to your `div` element.
2. Create a separate `red` class to set the `border-color`. This class will be added for a short period and then removed.
3. Add the below JS code to add the class on `load` and then remove after a few seconds (time-out).

```js
window.onload = function() { // add class on page load
  document.getElementById('ribbon').classList.add('red');
  setTimeout(removeHighlight, 2000); // call function to remove highlight after 2 seconds.
}

function removeHighlight() {
  document.getElementById('ribbon').classList.remove('red');
}
```

```css
div.ribbonDisplay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #c7c7c7;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  height: 6px;
  top: 8px;
  left: 7px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-bottom-width: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 1s ease; /* added for the transition effect */
  -moz-transition: border-color 1s ease;
  transition: border-color 1s ease;
}
#ribbon.red { /* to make the selector more specific so that it over-ride initial setting */
  border-color: red;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id='ribbon' class='ribbonDisplay'>Ribbon</div>
```

**Note:** `classList.add` and `classList.remove` are part of HTML5 APIs and hence would not work in IE < 8. Refer this [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) for Browser compatibility list.

**JS without HTML5 API:**

```js
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('ribbon').className += ' red';
    setTimeout(removeHighlight, 2000);
}

function removeHighlight() {
    var classes = document.getElementById('ribbon').className
    document.getElementById('ribbon').className = classes.replace(' red', ''); //replaces red in the class attribute with null/blank.
}
```

```css
div.ribbonDisplay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #c7c7c7;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  height: 6px;
  top: 8px;
  left: 7px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-bottom-width: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 1s ease; /* added for the transition effect */
  -moz-transition: border-color 1s ease;
  transition: border-color 1s ease;
}
#ribbon.red { /* to make the selector more specific so that it over-ride initial setting */
  border-color: red;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id='ribbon' class='ribbonDisplay'>Ribbon</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using `animation` would have been a much more easiest way to go.

```
@keyframes flash {
  from { border-color: #f00; }
  to { border-color: #ccc }
}

div.ribbonDisplay {
  border-color: #f00; /* in case if you want any delay time */
  animation: flash 2s ease-out forwards;
}
```

You could even set a delay time to the animation:

```
div.ribbonDisplay {
  animation: flash 2s ease-out .5s forwards;
}
```